# Реализация количество просмотров на странице Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, сервер, http

Как лучше реализовать количество просмотров страницы?
На данный момент у меня на обоих страницах показывает общее количество просмотров, а хотелось бы на каждой в отдельности.

```
const http = require('http');

let userCount = 0;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    userCount++;

    if (req.url === '/') {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type' : 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'});
        res.write('<h1>Корневая страница</h1>');
        res.write('Количество просмотров:' + userCount);
        res.end('<a href="/about">Ссылка на страницу /about</a>');
    } else if (req.url === '/about') {
        
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type' : 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'});
        res.write('<h1><h1>Страница about</h1>');
        res.write('Количество просмотров:' + userCount);
        res.end('<a href="/">Ссылка на страницу /</a>');
    } else {
        res.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type' : 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'});
        res.write('<h1><h1>Ошибка! Страница 404...</h1>')
        res.end('<a href="/">Вернуться на главную страницу</a>');    
    }
});

const port = 3000;

server.listen(port);
```

Comment: счетчик нужно завести для каждой страницы

Answer (score -1):

Может быть так?

```
const http = require('http');

let userCountRoot = 0;
let userCountAbout = 0;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {    
    if (req.url === '/') {
        userCountRoot++;
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type' : 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'});
        res.write('<h1>Корневая страница</h1>');
        res.write('Количество просмотров:' + userCountRoot);
        res.end('<a href="/about">Ссылка на страницу /about</a>');
    } else if (req.url === '/about') {
        userCountAbout++;
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type' : 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'});
        res.write('<h1><h1>Страница about</h1>');
        res.write('Количество просмотров:' + userCountAbout);
        res.end('<a href="/">Ссылка на страницу /</a>');
    } else {
        res.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type' : 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'});
        res.write('<h1><h1>Ошибка! Страница 404...</h1>')
        res.end('<a href="/">Вернуться на главную страницу</a>');    
    }
});

const port = 3000;

server.listen(port);
```

Это, разумеется, максимально в лоб. Но что тут выдумывать-то еще?